# SCCM URL to query MP for distribution points based on client subnet

Tags: sccm, sccm-2012

I once saw a URL used to query the MP for the list of distribution points available for a client based on the clients subnet. The subnet or IP address was sent as an argument in the URL, and the MP would return a XML containing the available DPs.

It's similar to the data returned for this URL: http:///sms_mp/.sms_aut?mplist, but with DPs instead.

I've been looking for this URL for a long time, but can't find it anywhere.

Do you know what URL is this?

Thanks!